# Eclipselink Exception: Isolated Data is not currently supported

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

> Exception [EclipseLink-7114] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.1.v20130824-981335c): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException  Exception
>   Description: Isolated Data is not currently supported within a Client
>   Session Broker.

This exception happens during the starting of the application. **The frustrating aspect of this exception is that it is occurring randomly!**

The application uses Eclipselink's [Composite Persistence Unit](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Composite) feature. Upon start of the application, it prints following log messages before throwing this exception:

```
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-11-27 12:26:24.125--ServerSession(1424344630)--PU1 login successful
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-11-27 12:26:24.14--ServerSession(1670276602)--PU2 login successful
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-11-27 12:26:24.14--ServerSession(780412982)-- PU3 login successful
```

Following which a few messages of the following kind are printed:

```
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2016-11-27 12:26:24.156--ServerSession(1424344630)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [attrname] for the entity class [class fully_qualified_class_name] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
```

Then the PU logout messages are printed as follows:

```
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-11-27 12:26:24.906--ServerSession(1424344630)--PU1 logout successful
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-11-27 12:26:24.906--ServerSession(1670276602)--PU2 logout successful
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-11-27 12:26:24.906--ServerSession(780412982)--PU3 logout successful
```

Immediately after that the validation exception about isolated data is thrown:

```
Nov 27, 2016 12:26:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [fully_qualified_class_name]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is Exception [EclipseLink-7114] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.3.v20150122-8d884e3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception Description: Isolated Data is not currently supported within a Client Session Broker. Session named PU3 contains descriptors representing isolated data.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:697)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:526)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Following is the `Composite PU` persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="compositePu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider> org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider </provider>
    <jar-file>PU1-entities.jar</jar-file>
    <jar-file>PU2-entities.jar</jar-file>
    <jar-file>PU3-entities.jar</jar-file>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.composite-unit" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Following is the structure of respective PU's persistence.xml. They all follow the similar structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="PU3" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    ---- list of fully qualified entity class names ----

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update" value="none" />
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none" />
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT" />
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist" value="" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Can you please share the persistence.xml

Comment: @simas_ch details about persistence.xml is added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Remove eclipselink.cache.shared.default because you have a composite persistence unit.

Comment: @simas_ch `eclipselink.cache.shared.default` is anyway set to `false`. Do you think removing will make any difference? I will anyway try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: yes by default EclispseLink uses the second level cache. so either remove it or set eclipselink.cache.shared.default=true

Comment: @simas_ch Thanks. The exception did go away after removing `eclipselink.cache.shared.default`. I have other applications that use composite persistence unit with shared.default set to false. But the error occurs only in one particular application. Hence, I am failing to understand the root cause. Can you please share any link to documentation that states that shared cache must be enabled for composite persistent unit feature to work. Also, please note that exception occurs randomly.

Comment: @simas_ch I have updated the question with the usage of joined inheritance tables in the application. Wondering if this has got anything to do with this exception!

Comment: Do you have relationships between Entities in different JARs?

Comment: No. We dont have relationship between entities in different jars. We have multi-tenant entities. Just wondering if that can cause any problem. I was just checking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824508/cache-isolation-level-warning-on-parent-entity

Comment: Setting both eclipselink.cache.shared.default and eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache to false did not solve the problem as stated in my answer below. Problem resurfaced again!

Comment: @simas_ch Sorry for the wrong answer. We do have relationship between entities in different JARs. Wondering how that can have any relationship with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

***WARNING: This is not the right answer. Problem reoccurred again!***

Setting both `eclipselink.cache.shared.default` and `eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache` to **false** eliminated isolated-data exception.

Having `eclipselink.cache.shared.default` set to false and having multi-tenant Joined Table Inheritance entities, triggered random occurrence of behavior explained in [Cache Isolation Level Warning on Parent Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824508/cache-isolation-level-warning-on-parent-entity). However, please note that I have no clue about the random behaviour though.

Setting `eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache` to false in addition to `eclipselink.cache.shared.default` having been set to false resulted in consistent elimination of isolated-data exception.

Comment: Is it possible to post more of your code, like entities, server details you're using, this way we can try to simulate locally...

Comment: @dscastro I will try to make the skeleton of the code and post. Thanks.